# Running the executable of hdl_simple_viewer.cpp from Point Cloud Library

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

The Point Cloud library comes with an executable pcl_hdl_viewer_simple that I can run (./pcl_hdl_viewer_simple) without any extra arguments to get live data from a Velodyne LIDAR HDL32.

The source code for this program is supposed to be [hdl_viewer_simple.cpp](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/visualization/tools/hdl_viewer_simple.cpp). A simplified version of the code is given on [this](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/hdl_grabber.php) page which cannot be compiled readily and requires a tiny bit of tweaking to make it compile.

My problem is that the executable that I build myself for both the versions are not able to run. I always get the smart pointer error "Assertion px!=0" error. I am not sure if I am not executing the program in the correct way or what. The executable is supposed to be executed like 
./hdl_viewer_simple -calibrationFile hdl32calib.xml -pcapFile file.pcap
in case of playing from previously recorded PCAP files or just ./hdl_viewer_simple if wanting to get live data from the real sensor. However, I always get the assertion failed error.

Has anyone been able to run the executables? I do not want to use the ROS drivers

Answer (score 0):

"Assertion px!=0" is occurring because your pointer is not initialized.

Now that being said, you could initialize it inside your routines, in case the pointer is NULL, especially for data input.

in [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/hdl_grabber.php), you can try updating the line 83 like this :

```
CloudConstPtr cloud(new Cloud); //initializing your pointer
```

and hopefully, it will work.

Cheers,

Comment: I get  a syntax error for CloudConstPtr cloud_(new Cloud) as well as 
for CloudConstPtr cloud_(new CloudConstPtr). Could you please take a look again?